# How to get name of paired MFI device to iPhone via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, ipod, external-accessory, mfi

I have a MFi keyboard. It is already paired to the iPhone via bluetooth.

I want to programmatically get the name of the paired keyboard. I searched some forums and they say it's possible to do that...

But how do we get the name using "External Accessory"?

A sample code would help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: The MFi program is not available to the general public -- most of us simply don't have access to the information we'd need to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your EAAccessory object and then call the property name on your accessory object

```
NSLog(@"%@",connectedAccessory.name);
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't get any response then so i had dropped the plan, but i'll try and check it again.

Comment: @Pallavi: Are you able to get the external paired device name? Could you post the sample code if you succeeded in getting the accessory name.